# Extract token positions from String Array- Java

Tags: java, string, search, text, arrays

I'm just asking whether there is a simple way to extract a string out of a string array in java.
For example if i've the input:

```
String searchtext = "The one thing";
String source = "the one Thing in life is to not do in java";
String annote = "det num nn pp nn cop to neg vv pp nn";
```

I want the output (I don't want to use a regex because my searchtext will vary)

```
det num nn
```

Will this code work????

```
String searchtext = "The one thing";
String source = "the one Thing in life is to not do in java";
String annote = "det num nn pp nn cop to neg vv pp nn";
String[] annotelist = annote.split(" ");

List<String> sourcelist = Array.asList(sourcetext.split(" ")); 
search_startpt = searchlist.indexof(search[0]);

String[] searchannote = annotelist[search_startpt];
for (int j=1; j<sourcelist.length(); j++) 
  searchanote[j] = annotelist[sear_startpt+j];

System.out.println(StringUtils.join(searchannoate, " "));
```

Originally, I've tried the code below:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

String searchtext = "The one thing";
String[] search  = searchtext.split(" ");
String source = "the one Thing in life is to not do in java";
String[] sourcelist  = source.split(" ");
String annote = "det num nn pp nn cop to neg vv pp nn";
String[] annotelist = annote.split(" ");

int search_startpt = 0;

for (int i=0; i<sourcelist.length(); i++) {
  if (sourcelist[i].equalsIgnoreCase(search[0])) {
    for (int j=1; j<search.length(); j++) {
      if (sourcelist[i+j].equalsIgnoreCase(search[j]) ==0) break;
      if (sourcelist[i+search.length()].equalsIgnoreCase(search[search.length()-1])) search_startpt = i;
    }
  }
}

String[] searchannote = annotelist[search_startpt];

for (int j=1; j<sourcelist.length(); j++) 
  searchanote[j] = annotelist[sear_startpt+j];

System.out.println(StringUtils.join(searchannoate, " "));
```

Comment: Thanks Gray, String.indexof(X) can find the searchtext char position but not the resultant searchannoate.

Comment: Right, sorry, didn't parse the complete question.  @solendil's answer is the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all `==` between strings with `.equals()`. Example :

```
if (sourcelist[i] == search[0]) {
```

becomes

```
if (sourcelist[i].equals(search[0])) {
```

Reason is that when you `split()` a String, all created `String` objects are new and different, even if their content is the same. The `==` operator tests that two references point to the same object, while the `.equals()` tests whether two objects have the same content.

Comment: thanks but is there a shorter way of extracting the required strings from the sourcetext?

Comment: You can always convert your arrays to Lists and do an indexOf `Arrays.asList(sourcelist).indexOf(search[0]);`

Comment: Meaning shorter than `split()`? Not that I know of... As of the main algorithm, there's plenty of other solutions. For example, `sourceText.index(search)`, then count number of spaces A before this index, count number of tokens B in search term, and take elements A to B from annote array. Might be shorter...

Comment: Will this work? `List<String> sourcelist = Array.asList(source.split(" "));` and then i do a `sourcelist.indexof(search[0])`;

Comment: I'm getting the error `The method asList(String[]) is undefined for the type Array` from the `List<String> sourcelist = Array.asList(source.split(" "))` line. How do i resolve that?